# Programatically check when Facebook Graph API access token expires

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there an API end point to get the information available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=%5BTOKEN%5D)?

I would like to be able to check in code when the access token expires.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check when a fb-token will expire](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11613864/how-do-i-check-when-a-fb-token-will-expire)

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific end point to check access_tokens, instead you can call `/me` using the access_token you have until it returns an error.

Comment: Thanks - That doesn't tell me when it expires though if I understand you correctly, just lets me know the point at which it expires which any other calls with the access token would also do.

Comment: Exactly. You can only find out when it expires if you make a note of the expiration time in the `signed_request` your app gets from Facebook. This time is updated whenever you get a new access token.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in with facebook javascript SDK, it gives you an "expiresIn" value, under "autheResponse" object.

I believe this number to be in seconds.

Unfortunately i'm not sure how to extend that number, or request a longer expiration date, etcs.

Apologises for not being super precise, facebook API always leave this "unsure" feeling.

EDIT: Maybe you might want to check instructions for "extending tokens":

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens